# Asp.net web form - Search bar returns empty result after keeping it open for more than 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET web form with search box functionality hosted on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 10. When I test in Visual Studio with internal IIS Express(chrome) as local host, it works fine. After I deploy in IIS, it works fine in the browser for the first 20 min.
[image: Fresh while deployed in IIS (works well upto 20 min)]

Then if the page is open in Chrome for more than 20 min, it displays as usual but when I type something in search bar, search results are totally empty and everything is just empty. The only work around is to close the browser, wait for 20 min not using the browser and then reopen a new browser. Then it works. This is totally not a meaningful solution [image: After keeping it open for 20 min in browser].

I assumed it might be because of time out, but actually I did not specify any timeout with 20 min. Also, after researching a bit, I found may be it could be because of Idle Time-out  in IIS. But I actually `do not want any time out` and want to let it function normally for every time I try to search. It is not any login specific function also to say like session is expired or something. It is just a classic local intranet website. Even if the user keeps the browser page open for days, it still should work once someone enters something. It is something similar to search box in a normal page where you can search from the list of items.

I am unable to debug also, because it happens only after it is deployed in IIS. But in visual studio even if I keep it idle for 2 days and see, it still works fine. Hence I am not knowing how to debug, and how to find the cause of this behaviour. Could someone kindly help me with this or atleast show me a directin how can I proceed? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, clearly your session is going out of scope. So, you could consider using viewstate. (assuming the session objects are small). You could also set the timeout on the page to be longer, or even consider some client side js code that hits the server every 1 minute.

Comment: You can control ASP.NET session timeout in web.config via sessionState parameter, it's in minutes.

Comment: I am aware of Timeout/Sessionstate parameter. But even if I change it, still it will be with a time limit. As I mentioned above, I do not want any time out, as it is not like a login page or something.

Comment: You can enable IIS logging for your web application and check the logs for related errors or warnings, which might help you pinpoint the problem.